# Returning all fields from MonoDB matched by value of a field embedded in Object type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

for the following MongoDB results, i'm trying to write a query where the name filed is NOT `Demo` or `Demo 2` the Items.location is `equal to hongkong`:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("573ac4d1ad364cd534a03e15"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2016-05-17T07:14:25.341Z"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2016-05-17T07:14:25.341Z"),
    "name": "Testing",
    "Items": {
        "date": "18052016",
        "location": "hongkong"
    },
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": ObjectID("573ac4d1ad364cd534a03e16"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2016-05-17T07:14:25.341Z"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2016-05-17T07:14:25.341Z"),
    "name": "Demo",
    "Items": {
        "date": "18052016",
        "location": "hongkong demo"
    },
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": ObjectID("573ac4d1ad364cd534a03e16"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2016-05-17T07:14:25.341Z"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2016-05-17T07:14:25.341Z"),
    "name": "Demo 2",
    "Items": {
        "date": "18052016",
        "location": "hongkong demo"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

My query looks like:

```
mySchema.statics.testing = function *() {
    var output =  this.find(
        {
            name: {
                $nin: ["Demo", "Demo 2"]
            }
        }
        ,{
            Items: {
                $elemMatch: { location: "hongkong" }
            }
        }).exec();

    return output;
};
```

and my schema is below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    Items: Object
}, { timestamps: true });
```

The query seems to only return the `"_id"` field for the matched where as i want the all the fields returned, name, Items..etc. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed. Needed:

```
var output =  this.find(
        {
            name: {
                $nin: ["Demo", "Demo 2"]
            },
            "Items.location" : "hongkong"
        }).exec();

    return output;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
mySchema.statics.testing = function (fn) {
        this.find(
            {
                name: {
                    $nin: ["Demo", "Demo 2"]
                },
                "Items.location": "hongkong"
            })
            .exec(function (err, docs) {
                fn(err, docs)
            })
    };
```